# multiprocessing.queue cant get data after gunicorn worker timeout

Tags: python, gunicorn, python-multiprocessing

I have a FLASK APP and use gunicorn(sync mode) as the web server. To async push information, I use “gunicorn server hook” to start an maintain process(multiprocessing.Process()) when gunicorn startup, and use multiprocessing.Queue() (it actually is logging.handlers.QueueHandler(Queue) to be compatible with python logging) to send messages.
But i found that if the gunicorn worker restarts when “[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT”, the maintain process wont get the message from queue send by gunicorn workers(the queue.qsize() not 0, and according to log, it put the message to queue successfully, but Queue.get(timeout) raise Empty exception), but can get message from gunicorn main process. 
My log:

```
  34 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 06:32:43,552 wechat_middle.py[line:34] DEBUG recive <LogRecord: wechat, 40, /www_upload/src/api_server.py, 543, "{'tag_list': 1, 'msg': 'company_test sid:8607550100000080 id: 8607550100000080 his: 1', 'lastsend': 'serial_error'}">
  35 pid:23930 wechat    : 2017-10-10 06:38:56,805 api_server.py[line:543] ERROR {'tag_list': 1, 'msg': 'company_test sid:8607550100000080 id: 8607550100000080 his: 1', 'lastsend': 'serial_error'}
  36 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 06:38:56,807 wechat_middle.py[line:34] DEBUG recive <LogRecord: wechat, 40, /www_upload/src/api_server.py, 543, "{'tag_list': 1, 'msg': 'company_test sid:8607550100000080 id: 8607550100000080 his: 1', 'lastsend': 'serial_error'}">
  37 pid:24887 wechat    : 2017-10-10 07:07:50,904 api_server.py[line:543] ERROR {'tag_list': 1, 'msg': 'company_test sid:8607550100000080 id: 8607550100000080 his: 1', 'lastsend': 'serial_error'}
  38 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:07:51,810 maintain_task.py[line:274] INFO current qsize: 1, debug_size: 0
  39 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:07:55,813 maintain_task.py[line:274] INFO current qsize: 1, debug_size: 1
  40 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:07:57,813 wechat_middle.py[line:25] INFO in debug mode, queue id 139972199063056, size 1
  41 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:07:59,816 wechat_middle.py[line:31] ERROR in debug mode, queue get nothing.
  42 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:07:59,816 maintain_task.py[line:274] INFO current qsize: 1, debug_size: 1
  43 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:08:00,817 maintain_task.py[line:281] ERROR queue is empty
  44 pid:24831 wechatlog : 2017-10-10 07:08:00,818 maintain_task.py[line:283] ERROR the message block the queue: None
```

between 2017-10-10 06:38:56 to 2017-10-10 07:07:50, the gunicorn log report this:

```
 [2017-10-10 06:41:08 +0800] [23906] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:24838)
```

My code:

```
maintain_task.py
def wechat_push_thread(queue):
    we = wechat_middler_ware(queue=queue)
    wechat_log_logger = configs.make_logger_handler('wechatlog', filename='wechat')
    wechat_log_logger.info(f'queue id: {id(queue)}')
    debug_size = 0
    while True:
        try:
            we.listen(2)
        except Exception as e:
            wechat_log_logger.exception(e)
        # for debug
        if queue.qsize() > 0:
            wechat_log_logger.info(f'current qsize: {queue.qsize()}, debug_size: {debug_size}')
            if debug_size == queue.qsize():
                if we.debug_flag:
                    try:
                        msg = queue.get(timeout=1)
                    except Empty:
                        msg = None
                        wechat_log_logger.error(f'queue is empty')
                    wechat_log_logger.error(f'the message block the queue: {msg}')
                we.debug_flag = True
            debug_size = queue.qsize()
        else:
            we.debug_flag = False
            debug_size = 0
        # endfor debug
        if quit_event.wait(timeout=2):
            break
    logger.info('wechat_push_thread clean env')

wechat_middle.py
class wechat_middler_ware:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.q = queue
        self.logger = configs.make_logger_handler('wechatlog', filename='wechat')
        self.push_api = Push_Server(logger=self.logger)
        self.debug_flag = False

    def listen(self, timeout):
        while True:
            if self.debug_flag:
                self.logger.info(f'in debug mode, queue id {id(self.q)}, size {self.q.qsize()}')
            try:
                msg = self.q.get(timeout=timeout)
                self.logger.debug(f'recive {msg}')
            except Empty:
                if self.debug_flag:
                    self.logger.error(f'in debug mode, queue get nothing.')
                break
            else:
                ...
```

Comment: when I reduce the queue size, like 2, it will cause Queue.full exception. And Queue.get() still get Empty.

Answer (score 0):

According to py doc:

> Warning If this method is used when the associated process is using a
>   pipe or queue then the pipe or queue is liable to become corrupted and
>   may become unusable by other process. Similarly, if the process has
>   acquired a lock or semaphore etc. then terminating it is liable to
>   cause other processes to deadlock.

The gunicorn master killed the "timeout" worker, so the queue has becomed unusable by other process.
Now, i use multiprocessing.manager.queue instead of multiprocessing.queue. it can work well even the worker is killed by the master.